# Accessing parent "isolated" scope from child directive

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have a nested directive. I am trying to access the scope of the parent directive (which is isolated) but can't seem to make it work. I get undefined errors when trying to log it out to the console.

Here's an example of what I am trying to get to work.

```
app.directive("myParentControl", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {},

        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.propertyOne = "PropertyOne"
    },

    link: function(scope, element) {
        console.log(scope.propertyOne);
    }
  }
});

app.directive("myChildControl", function() {
    return {
        require: "^myParentControl",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, myParentControlCtrl) {
            //Undefined
            console.log(myparentControlCtrl.propertyOne);
            //Not visible in scope inspector
            myParentControlCtrl.newValue = "New Value";
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the variable to the `$scope`: `$scope.propertyOne = "PropertyOne"`, but try to access it from the controller: `console.log(myparentControlCtrl.propertyOne)`. Of course it is undefined.

Set the property in the controller:

```
controller: function($scope) {
    this.propertyOne = "PropertyOne";
},
```

If you need to access it from the template of `myParentControl`, put the controller in the scope using the `controllerAs` property:

```
app.directive("myParentControl", function() {
    return {
        ...
        controllerAs: "ctrl",
        ...
    };
});
```

From the template access it as:

```
<span>{{ ctrl.propertyOne }</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I do it this way though, I seem to no longer have access to the controller from my console log in the link function of myParentControl - how would I maintain that connection? Also, I thought the idea of a required directive was passing along the $scope? Sorry for the confusion - just trying to get my head around it.

Comment: In order to access this directive's controller from the link function, `require` this directive and proceed as normal. - No, requiring a directive does not bring in the scope, just the controller.

Comment: Requiring the controller that's declaring the thing to be required... ok..... Well, it works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the scope of the parent directive using `scope` in child directives.

```
myApp.directive("myChildControl", function() {
    return {
        require: "^myParentControl",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, myParentControl) {
            console.log(scope.propertyOne);
            //Not visible in scope inspector
            myParentControl.newValue = "New Value";
        }
      }
    })
```

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nitishkumarsingh13/guhuz9zt/)